# radio input styling not working for firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I've styled my radio input using the css below.  However in Firefox, a completely different radio appears and I am unable to style it at all.

It works perfectly in safari and chrome yet I cannot seem to figure out why it isn't working in Firefox.

```css
 input[type=checkbox] {
   border: 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
   height: 20px;
   margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   vertical-align: -5px;
   width: 20px;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:before {
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 20px;
   left: 0px;
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   transition: opacity .15s linear;
   top: 0px;
   width: 20px;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:after {
   border: 2px solid #EC407A;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 23px;
   left: -5px;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: -9px;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transition: opacity .15s linear;
   width: 27px;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
   opacity: 1;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:focus {
   box-shadow: none;
   outline: 0px;
 }
 .radio-wrapper {
   position: relative;
 }
 input[type='radio'] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -ms-appearance: none;
   -o-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   position: relative;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
   background: #cbd1d8;
   border: none;
   color: #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   outline: none;
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes click-wave {
   0% {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     opacity: 0.35;
     position: relative;
   }
   100% {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     margin-left: -80px;
     margin-top: -80px;
     opacity: 0.0;
   }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes click-wave {
   0% {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     opacity: 0.35;
     position: relative;
   }
   100% {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     margin-left: -80px;
     margin-top: -80px;
     opacity: 0.0;
   }
 }
 @keyframes click-wave {
   0% {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     opacity: 0.35;
     position: relative;
   }
   100% {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     margin-left: -80px;
     margin-top: -80px;
     opacity: 0.0;
   }
 }
 .option-input {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
   background: #7CE1C9;
   border: none;
   color: #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   outline: none;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 0.5rem;
 }
 .option-input:hover {
   background: #9faab7;
 }
 .option-input:checked {
   background: #7CE1C9;
 }
 .option-input:checked::before {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   position: relative;
   content: '\2716';
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 14.66667px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 20px;
 }
 .option-input:checked::after {
   -webkit-animation: click-wave 0.65s;
   -moz-animation: click-wave 0.65s;
   animation: click-wave 0.65s;
   background: #7CE1C9;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   position: relative;
 }
 .option-input.radio {
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 .option-input.radio::after {
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 input[type='radio'] + label {
   user-select: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding-left: 30px;
 }
 input[type='radio'] + label:before,
 input[type='radio'] + label:after {
   background: #fff;
   background-clip: padding-box;
   border: 2px solid #EC407A;
   border-radius: 50%;
   bottom: 3px;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 16px;
   left: 3px;
   margin-top: -8px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   width: 16px;
 }
 input[type='radio'] + label:after {
   background: #7CE1C9;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   transform: scale(0);
   -wekbit-transform: scale(0);
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }
 input[type='radio']:focus + label:before {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #EC407A;
 }
 input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
   border-color: #EC407A;
 }
 input[type='radio']:checked + label:after {
   transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);
 }
 `
```

```html
<form>
  <li class='initialForm'><span class='optionText'>$option1</span><strong><input type='radio' class='option-input radio option1' id='$id' value='1' name='option'></strong>
  </li>
  <li class='initialForm'><span class='optionText'>$option2</span><strong><input type='radio' class='option-input radio option2' id='$id' value='2' name='option'></strong>
  </li>
</form>
```

Comment: You perfectly added the CSS and HTML. Would you mind using [code snippets](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), to make it easier to see what you're talking about?

Comment: you have this `input[type='radio']:checked + label:after` but where is your `label`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `-webkit` CSS prefixes, which is specifically for Chrome and Safari (or webkit based browsers).

You should ALSO use `-moz` CSS prefixes, specifically for Firefox.  And, of course, if you want to support IE, they may have additionally or different stylings for certain methods.

Specifically for your `transform` method, in Firefox it is considered experimental, and perhaps `-moz-transform` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://clarknikdelpowell.com/blog/styling-radio-buttons-select-boxes-in-firefox/

Even though it’s a part of Chrome, Safari and Firefox (-webkit-appearance, -moz-appearance), isn’t actually CSS. A lot of people use -webkit-appearance:none to reset the appearance of everything from buttons, inputs, you name it. However, there are a couple of  Firefox bugs that make -moz-appearance:none a dangerous proposition.

Since appearance does not work completely on both checkboxes and radio buttons. You can still style radio buttons, you’re just going to have to use a bit of trickery in order to pull it off. Here’s how you’d do it.

1. Set the radio input to display: none.
2. Style a span adjacent to the radio button the way you’d like to style the radio button.
3. Toggle its appearance using the :checked attribute.

---

For Browser compatibility and  further info see source
Toggle its appearance using the :checked attribute.

Comment: How do you plan on toggling the radio (and using the `:checked` attribute) when the `display` is set to `none`?

Answer (score -1):

I found this blog post online and it tackles the problem you are having: https://clarknikdelpowell.com/blog/styling-radio-buttons-select-boxes-in-firefox/

edit:
In general, it's considered bad practice to style radio buttons directly. The reason you are having an issue is because `-webkit-appearance, -moz-appearance` is not actually CSS. Since you can't style the radio buttons directly, you have to use a bit of a work around.

1. Set the radio input to display: none.
2. Style a span adjacent to the radio button the way you’d like to style the radio button.
3. Toggle its appearance using the :checked attribute.

I sketched up a basic example on jsFiddle using some of the code you specified: https://jsfiddle.net/o3nurghw/2/

HTML:

```
<form>
  <li class='initialForm'>
      <span class='optionText'>$option1</span>
      <input type='radio' class='option-input radio option1' id='$id' value='1' name='option' />
      <span class="overlay"></span> <!-- the adjacent span -->
  </li>
  <li class='initialForm'>
    <span class='optionText'>$option2</span>
    <input type='radio' class='option-input radio option2' id='$id' value='2' name='option' />
    <span class="overlay"></span> <!-- the adjacent span -->
  </li>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.initialForm {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;    
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
    background: #cbd1d8;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.radio {
    display: none;
}
.radio:checked + span:before {
    width: .75em;
    height: .75em;
    margin: .125em;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```